# accumulating results for each row in a text while looping

Tags: python, statistics, nlp

Why I'm having accumulating results for each row in this example:

my text example contains two rows:

he

the

I need the result for each row in a my text as a separate result

```
for row in sample_file:
    for word in row.split():
        for c in word:
            product = product*(float(char_value_en.get(c, 0)))
final_prob_es = prob_es*tweet_prob_es
print 'Spanish Prob'+' '+'='+' '+str(final_prob_es)
print row
```

my output is:

Spanish Prob = 0.698565816073

he

Spanish Prob = 0.836227448039

the

Spanish Prob = 0.957639196166

he

Spanish Prob = 1.14635466369

the

Comment: You should try to explain a bit more. What do you want to get?

Comment: I want to get an assigned value for each letter in each word in each line and print out this value (it is the sum of logs of some values for each letter, this part works for me), but the problem is, it is accumulating the results.

Comment: @ALS_WV Can you validate the indentation in your code please?

Comment: You wanna now how many "a", how many "b", how many "c" ... in the input file ?

Comment: I'm trying to find the a multiplication value for each line in my text. each letter has a value which can be ready from another file. The most important thing is why the values of production of multiple rows in my text are accumulating? the problem of my program is the code that i posted

Comment: @ALS_WV From the looks of it you are not reseting the values you need for your calculations on new iterations.

Comment: exactly, but how i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments

**rows.txt**

```
aab
abc
acc
```

**script.py**

```py
char_value_en = {
    'a': 0.1,
    'b': 0.2,
    'c': 0.3
}

res = {}

with open('rows.txt') as f:
    for row in f:
        for word in row.split():
            for c in word:
                if c not in res:
                    res[c] = 1
                res[c] *= char_value_en.get(c, 1)

print(res)

# >> {'a': 0.00010000000000000003, 'b': 0.04000000000000001, 'c': 0.027}
```